# Why an error occurs when I try to map a redux array?

Tags: reactjs, redux, array.prototype.map

I'm using React Hooks + Redux.
I have an object which contains an array:

```
{
  id: "c59a3203-af94-49c3-abb6-87073619fbce"
  type: "block"
  attributes: {
    title: "THis is the first title"
    status: "published"
    published: true
    attachments: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] <== this is array I need to access 
    articles: [{…}]
    external_resources: []
  }
}
```

On Click, I load the attachments array (see below) into Redux and extract it in my component by using the hook `useSelector`:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "f15dbb5b-79e5-4204-9161-77bd6917814b", type: "attachment", attributes: {…}}
1: {id: "4971d5c8-df8e-4930-bafe-a12160493371", type: "attachment", attributes: {…}}
2: {id: "a275d3da-ad26-4144-819c-8f2db972ad6e", type: "attachment", attributes: {…}}
3: {id: "c15ea08c-a12f-4822-84bf-580f27fa1c94", type: "attachment", attributes: {…}}
```

As you can see this is an array, but for whatever reason, when I call it from my component by using `useSelector` and map it, I get the following error message:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Here the component:

```
const attachmentsData = useSelector(
  state => state.attachments.attachmentsData,
  shallowEqual
);

console.log(attachmentsData.map(x => x)) <== ERROR
console.log(attachmentsData) <=== SHOWS THE ARRAY WITHOUT ERRORS
```

This is the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    attachmentsRaw: [],
    attachmentsData: []
};

const attachmentsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ATTACHMENTS.GET_START:
            return {
                ...state,
                attachmentsRaw: getLoadingState()
            };

        case ATTACHMENTS.GET_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                attachmentsRaw: getReadyState(action.data),
                attachmentsData: action.data
            };

        case ATTACHMENTS.GET_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                attachmentsRaw: getErrorState()
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
export default attachmentsReducer;
```

What am I doing wrong? 
I can say that when the component loads, Redux takes a fraction of a second to load the data, which means in my component first render, the constant `attachmentsData` is an empty array [].

Any help is appreciated.
Joe

Answer (score 0):

`attachmentsData` may still be undefined or not populated at the time you try to map over it to fix it add this to your code `attachmentsData && attachmentsData.length && attachmentsData.map...`

Comment: This works, but it doesn't seem the right way to do it.

Comment: You either need to otherwise make sure that things are defined before using them, or check on them before using them.

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading the data into Redux? If you have the static data available on load you should put it into the reducer's `initialState` instead of injecting it afterwards.

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state/

Comment: I dispatch the data through an action type. I've updated the code above, you can see the reducer. The data is available on successfully loaded.

Comment: Can you share the functions `getLoadingState` and `getErrorState`? You really should not be calling functions in your reducer in this way.

Comment: ```export const getLoadingState = (state = {}) => ({
  ...state,
  isLoading: true,
  isLoaded: false,
  isError: false
});```

Comment: ```export const getErrorState = (data = {}) => ({
  data,
  isLoading: false,
  isLoaded: false,
  isError: true
});```

Comment: export const isLoading = (state = {}) => !!state.isLoading;
export const isError = (state = {}) => !!state.isError;

Comment: Ashraf Slamang,   how would you do the loading/loaded/error states?

Comment: That could be an issue there - you're converting your initial state array into an object.

Comment: Also, swap your `console.log` statements so you can see the data before the error:
```
console.log(attachmentsData) <=== SHOWS THE ARRAY WITHOUT ERRORS
console.log(attachmentsData.map(x => x)) <== ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the attachmentsData existence first then you can map the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting data before its filling array

use this

attachmentsData ? attachmentsData.map(x => x) : void 0

Answer (score 0):

Following what Shmili and Study Mania suggested above, a cleaner solution I have found is:

```
(attachmentsData || []).map(item => ( ....
```

It's weird. In the console log, I can see that `attachmentsData` is rendered 3 times. The first time as an empty array, as configured in redux, the second time as undefined (this is where the issue is) and the 3rd time as a filled array.

So, I will have to investigate why, first, it renders 3 times and second why the second time around it's undefined.

I will post here when I fix the undefined.